# NSTimeZone difference to GMT

Tags: iphone, nscalendar, nstimezone

I need to get the information of the difference between users timezone, to GMT London time, in hours, or minutes.

Anyone can help?

I've been looking around and i'm kind of confused.

Thanks,

rui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSTimeZone has a method called [`secondsFromGMT`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000190-CACDBJJF).

> **Return Value**
>   The current difference in seconds between the receiver and Greenwich Mean Time.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps you:

```
NSInteger hours, min;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterGMT = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

//GMT Time Zone
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatterGMT setTimeZone:gmt];

dateFormatterGMT.dateFormat = @"h";
hours = [[dateFormatterGMT stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];
NSLog(@"%ld", hours);

dateFormatterGMT.dateFormat = @"mm";
min = [[dateFormatterGMT stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];
NSLog(@"%ld", min);

//User Time Zone
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterUser = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *userDate = [NSDate date];

dateFormatterUser.dateFormat = @"h";
hours = [[dateFormatterUser stringFromDate:userDate] intValue];
NSLog(@"%ld", hours);

dateFormatterUser.dateFormat = @"mm";
min = [[dateFormatterUser stringFromDate:userDate] intValue];
NSLog(@"%ld", min);

[dateFormatterUser release];
```